# springboot application.properties corethreads doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, threadpool

I configure tomcat maxthreads and corethreads in application.properties , I print the executor.getMaxPoolSize() and executor.getCorePoolSize() in console log,but every server.tomcat.xxxx properties doesn't ,except server.port.
How can I fix it?

```
server.port=8081
server.tomcat.threads.max=200
server.tomcat.threads.core=20
server.tomcat.connection-timeout=80000
```

Answer (score 0):

executor.getMaxPoolSize() and executor.getCorePoolSize()  are  wrong way . application.properties is worked